# Does the following condition make a function $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $u_n\to u$ point-wise, and $\|u_n\|_2<C$ for all $n$. Does this imply $u\in L^2$?

This is my attempt. By boundedness of $u_n$, there's a subsequence that converges weakly to some function $f\in L^2$. But how do I prove $f= u$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you do not need the concept of weak convergence: Fatou's lemma implies
$$
\int u^2= \int \liminf_{n\to\infty}u_n^2\leqslant  \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int u_n^2\leqslant C.
$$